# iOS - Storing a reference to an object inside a variable

Tags: objective-c, ios

How would I go about making a reference to a UILabel inside a variable?

For example;

```
NSObject *instance;
switch (option) {
    case 0: 
    {
        NSObject *instance = self.player1;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        NSObject *instance = self.player2;
    }
}
instance.text = @"Hello"
```

I then want to change the text of the label that is in NSObject, but that doesn't appear to work.
So how would I go about doing this?

By the way, I'm new to Objective C, if you can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSObject *instance;
switch (option) {
    case 0: 
        instance = self.player1;  // Don't redeclare the variable, just set it.
        break;   // If we don't do this, we'll continue on to the next line!

    case 1:
        instance = self.player2;
        break;

    default:
        // If option isn't 0 or 1, we should try to handle it.
        instance = nil;
        break;
}
```

I highly suggest going through some Objective-C and/or C tutorials -- if you are having problems with the basics of the syntax, you will find it hard to make much progress. Stack Overflow isn't the best way to learn that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks, but say I then wanted to change the text attribute of the object in instance. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just like you said in the first place: `instance.text = @"Hello";`. Sorry, I missed that line in my version.

Comment: ... oh, and now I see that you added that line after I answered. Whatever.

Comment: Ok, tried that, and then XCode throws up an error, saying that `Property 'text' not found on object of type 'NSObject'.`

Comment: If your `self.player1` and `self.player2` really are `UILabel`s like you said, then change `NSObject` to `UILabel`.